# C#: Dictionary remains empty although value is added in a function

Tags: c#

I have a case where I don't understand why C# behaves like this.
The code is as follows:

```
private void Add(Dictionary<string,string> dct)
{
    dct.Add("ADD", "ADD");
}
private bool Do(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    AddDict(out dict);
    Add(dict);
    return true;
}
private bool AddDict(out Dictionary<string, string> dct)
{
    dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dct.Add("AddDict", "AddDict");
    return true;
}
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    
    Do(dct);                # dct is empty
    Add(dct);               # dct contains {[ADD, ADD]}
    AddDict(out dct);       # dct contains {[AddDict, AddDict]}
}
```

I don't understand why in the first case `dct` remains empty although in the function `Do` the variable `dict` contains value and as `dct` is a reference type I would expect that it should be non empty after `Do` has returned.

Comment: "Do" does not declare its dict parameter as out. So it can change the returned reference.

Comment: @Ralf Is it maybe because in Do the reference is changed due to `AddDict`?

Comment: Why you have Add and AddDict ? Are your doing some experiment?

Comment: @Chetan yes, I am doing some experiments.

Comment: try sendinf by Ref Do(ref Dictionary<string, string> dict)

Comment: Why don't you use `dct.Add` directly in Form_Load?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/parameter-passing-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: The fact that you're taking `dict` as a parameter, and then doing `AddDict(out dict)`, is the thing that's confusing you, I think. It would be clearer to do `AddDict(out var newDict); Add(newDict)`. See that `AddDict` is creating a *new* dictionary, and the subsequent call to `Add` is adding an element to this new dictionary. It's similar to if you did `dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(); Add(dict)` inside your method -- you're creating an entirely new dictionary and assigning that to the local `dict` variable

Comment: @ALL I know that it will work if I use `ref` or `out` in `Do`. I am asking why it is not working when I am not doing that as `Dictionary` is a reference type.

Comment: @canton7 thanks. I also think that this is the reason. As far as I understand `AddDict` creates a new reference by creating a new dictionary.

Comment: What's the observation of your experiment? I am sure you are aware that `new` operator in AddDict method creates new dictionary so whatever you have in the out parameter will be gone when you call `AddDict`.

Comment: In c#, by default, parameters are passed by value not by ref

Comment: Reference type means something is passed or assigned as reference(The reference is passed as a value). Not that the value of the reference can change. The thing pointed to by the reference can change not the reference itself. If you want to change the reference you need to use out or ref.

Comment: Thanks. Now it has become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I can help with some diagrams to better explain the behaviour.

Before doing that, it is important to understand that when we have a method expecting a reference type as one of its paramters, a copy of the **pointer** will be passed in when we call the method with an argument. Whenever the paramter is marked either with `ref` or `out`, that it is not the case anymore. Instead, a *pointer* towards the *pointer* of the argument is passed in.

Before moving on, we know that objects are always stored in the **heap**. Value types and pointers are stored wherever they are declared. For example, arguments of method that are of value type are stored in the **stack**. The same principle applies to a **pointer** defined inside a method or a local variable. Let's consider a simple example, `var person = new Person()`. In this case, the created object resulted from `new Person()` will be stored in the **heap**. The named pointer towards that object, that is `person`, will be stored in the **stack** and it will point to the newly created object that resides in the heap. Remember that this happens when we call a method. However, if we have an object that has fields, those will be stored in the **heap** alongside with the said object.

Now, moving on to the diagrams. When the code starts to execute, we create a new object (let's call it *Dictionary 1*) that is placed in the heap and a pointer towards it (that is placed on the stack) through the line `var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>()`. Moving on, we call the `Do()` method and the argument is saved on the stack. Remember that a reference type parameter copies the **pointer** of the argument. Thus, as it can be observed from the diagram below, we now have 2 pointers that point towards the same object on the heap. Moving further, the `AddDict()` methods is called, but in this case the argument is passed in with the `out` keyword. That means we now pass in a pointer towards the pointer. Again this is reflected on the diagram with the `dct` pointing towards the `dict`.

[image]

The `dct = new Dictionary<string, string>()` inside the `AddDict()` method is executed. This creates a new object on the heap and it makes the `dct` to point to it. Since we have a "pointing chain", that makes `dict` to point towards the new object. This is reflected in the diagram below. Then, the `"AddDict", "AddDict"` key-value pair is added to the pointed dictionary.

[image]

Since the `AddDict()` method has finished executing, all the resources related to it are discarded from the stack. Moving on, the `Add()` method is called inside the `Do() method. The behaviour is reflected in the diagram below.

[image]

The `Add()` method has finished executing so all its resources are disposed.

[image]

The same applies for the `Do()` method when it's done executing. However, as you can observe from the diagram below, there is no pointer pointing towards **Dictionary 2**, the one to which we added the key-value pairs.

[image]

Now the `Add()` method is called inside the `Form2_Load()` and then its resources are disposed

[image]

The same applies for the `AddDict()` method.

[image]

In the end we are left with this. As there are not pointers towards **Dictionary 1** and **Dictionary 2**, they will be collected by the Garbage Collector.

[image]

I really hope it makes sense and I shone some light regarding the behaviour that takes place behind the curtains.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 2):

1. When you call Do(dct) , method creates a copy of dct  that is called dict and dict reference the same memory heap that dct does. It is the same as

```
 var dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 var dict=dct;
```

now the both variables reference the same empty dictionary.

2. When after this you call AddDict(out dict) inside of Do, AddDict creates another dictionary inside of the method and return reference to the new dictionary to dict.  it is the same as

```
dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ADD", "ADD" }};
```

now dict inside of Do references a new dictionary with new records, but dct outside of Do still references the previous empty dictionary.

To fix it, both variables should reference the same peace of memory. You can do it using ref. Now everything is working as expected

```
Do(ref dct);   

private bool Do(ref Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    AddDict(out dict);
    Add(dict); 
    return true;
}
```